# Inserting <noscript> or similar within form tag (HTML, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, noscript

I have the following form:

```
<form id="signup" onsubmit="return false;">
  ... form content...
  <input class="button" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Where upon clicking the button, a JavaScript function `signup()` is called. This function uses an AJAX call to validate the form (compare to current database values), and then submit the form via a PHP function.

My question is: If the user has their JavaScript disabled in their browser, is there a way that I can modify the `<form>` tag to include an action and method?

Since HTML5 allows `<noscript>` tags within the body, I thought I'd try something like:

```
<form id="signup" <noscript>action="..." method="post"</noscript>>
```

but that doesn't work.

If the user has their JS enabled, I would like the AJAX calls to handle everything - it makes for a very clean user experience. BUT, I need it to still be functional for those people who have disabled their JS.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: since you already have onsubmit handler which always returns false for clients with JS enabled, why don't you simply do this: `<form onsubmit='return false;' method='post' action='otherpage.php'>`?

Comment: Very simple. I might double-up with this and Christian's answer, just for paranoia sake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking at it the wrong way round. You always want to include the `action` and `method` attributes on your form.

```
<form id="signup" action="/path/to/signup" method="post">
```

Then you bind a function to the `submit` event, and prevent the form from submitting by using `.preventDefault();` (I'm assuming jQuery usage here)

```
$('#signup').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // submit data via ajax here
});
```

This is much better, because you don't have to set the login URL in your javascript any more. You simply get it from the form.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: $('#signup').attr('action'),
  data: $('#signup').serialize()
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    // logged in (or not)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try Like This example**

```
<form action="calcSquare.php">
<p>
<label for=x>Number</label>:
<input id="x" name="x" type="number">
</p>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById('x');
var output = document.createElement('p');
output.textContent = 'Type a number; it will be squared right then!';
x.form.appendChild(output);
x.form.onsubmit = function () { return false; }
x.oninput = function () {
  var v = x.valueAsNumber;
  output.textContent = v + ' squared is ' + v * v;
};
</script>
<noscript>
<input type=submit value="Calculate Square">
</noscript>
</form>
```